# Sneaking while mounted

Tags: movement, pathfinder-2e, mounted-combat

So [now I know](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/185145/9552) that the only move action I can take while mounted is
dismount. But if I am sitting on an Animal Companion that is trained at Stealth, and I am too, can we somehow Sneak together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You would be Hiding

Because you are making no effort to move (yourself), you attempt a [Hide](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=62) check. Normally, taking almost any action ends your Stealth-related conditions gained/kept from Hide, but GM's are given significant leeway in allowing your to do so anyway.

> You cease being hidden if you do anything except Hide, Sneak, or Step. [...] **The GM might allow you to perform a particularly unobtrusive action without being noticed,** possibly requiring another Stealth check.

Normally, Command an Animal has the [Auditory](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=16) trait, but it is standard practice to train horses and other creatures used as mounts to be [led with your legs](https://www.wikihow.com/Steer-a-Horse-With-Only-Your-Legs) (wikihow link) instead of vocalization.

Because of this, I would personally allow, and expect most GM's to allow, a mounted character to roll Stealth to Hide their Commands while their AC rolls Stealth to Sneak them around.

There will be table variance, however, so I would discuss this with your GM before you enter a scene where you intend for it to work as I've described. They may ask that you spend downtime training your animal in this way, and could even replace the Auditory trait with [Manipulate](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=104) any time you are explicitly leading with your legs instead of verbally (although this has steep repercussions related to Reactions).